# How to join two data sets in which one data set (1D) used as variables?

Tags: r, join

I want to join two datasets in which one dataset (contains 1 dimension) is transposed and used as variables to join the other.

For example:

```
df = data.frame(A=1:3, B=3:5)
df2 = data.frame(lab = letters[1:5], C = seq(letters[1:5]))

df2_transposed <- data.frame(t(df2))
colnames(df2_transposed ) <- t(df2)[1,]
df2_new <- df2_transposed[2,]

# there are certainly alternatives without transposing data
```

I want to see a dataset like this :

```
  A B a b c d e
1 1 3 1 2 3 4 5
2 2 4 1 2 3 4 5
3 3 5 1 2 3 4 5
```

I tried two methods:

Method 1

```
library(plyr)
new <- join(df, df2_new, by = NULL, type = "left", match = "all")
```

which produces

```
  A B    a    b    c    d    e
1 1 3 <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA>
2 2 4 <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA>
3 3 5 <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA>
```

Method 2

```
new1 =  vector('list',3)
for (i in 1:nrow(df)){
   new1[[i]] = cbind(df[i,], df2_new[1,])
}

new2 = data.frame(matrix(unlist(new1), nrow= nrow(df), byrow=T), stringsAsFactors = F)
colnames(new2) <- c(colnames(df), colnames(df2_new))
```

Which produces

```
  A B a b c d e
1 1 3 1 1 1 1 1
2 2 4 1 1 1 1 1
3 3 5 1 1 1 1 1
```

Still no luck solving this problem.

Comment: `merge(df, df2_new)` works ?

Comment: Thanks @RonakShah Yes It works. Is it possible to join without transposing `df2`?

Comment: Not directly I suppose but akrun and thelatemail have given you some options with some transformation in `df2`

Comment: @RonakShah `merge(df, df2_new)` and `cbind(df, df2_new)` generate factor variables in my new data frame, any ideas why?

Answer (score 2):

We can use `cbind.fill`

```
library(rowr)
cbind.fill(df, df2_new)
#  A B a b c d e
#1 1 3 1 2 3 4 5
#2 2 4 1 2 3 4 5
#3 3 5 1 2 3 4 5
```

If we want to do this with 'df/df2'

```
library(tidyverse)
deframe(df2) %>%
       as.list %>%
       as_tibble %>%  
       cbind.fill(df, .)
```

---

Or similar to @thelatemails' approach

```
data.frame(df, as.list(deframe(df2)))
```

---

Or with `cbind` from `base R` with a friendly warning

```
cbind(df, df2_new)
```

Or replicate the rows of 'df2_new' and `cbind`

```
cbind(df, df2_new[rep(1, nrow(df)),])
```

Comment: `cbind` just works as you've shown, but I'm confused, is OP starting with `df` and `df2`, or with `df` and `df2_new`?

Comment: @thelatemail  I also got confused bcz his `join` was using `df/df2_new`.  I updated with another option that starts from 'df2'.  Thanks

Comment: Thanks, I started with `df2_new` but all of sudden I realised the problem was with `df2` and there must be a way without transposing the data frame.

Answer (score 2):

Using only base R, `cbind` a named `list`:

```
cbind(df, setNames(as.list(df2$C),df2$lab))
#  A B a b c d e
#1 1 3 1 2 3 4 5
#2 2 4 1 2 3 4 5
#3 3 5 1 2 3 4 5
```

Or the replacement form:

```
df[as.character(df2$lab)] <- as.list(df2$C)
df
#  A B a b c d e
#1 1 3 1 2 3 4 5
#2 2 4 1 2 3 4 5
#3 3 5 1 2 3 4 5
```

Or the non-replacement form of the replacement:

```
replace(df, as.character(df2$lab), as.list(df2$C))
```